# GraalVM native-image how to read resource file from Jar

Tags: java, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, substratevm

I have a jar file which contain some text file inside, I am trying to load the file as:

`InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);`

It doesn't work as error showing :

```
[SUB] java.lang.NullPointerException
[Thu Aug 27 12:07:48 SGT 2020][INFO] [SUB]  at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:167)
[Thu Aug 27 12:07:48 SGT 2020][INFO] [SUB]  at hellofx.HelloFX.readFileAsStringFromJar(HelloFX.java:116)
[Thu Aug 27 12:07:48 SGT 2020][INFO] [SUB]  at hellofx.HelloFX.test(HelloFX.java:107)
```

If I try to extract the resource file into classpath `src/main/resources`, then it is working fine.

My question is, could we read resource file from Jar (when running in [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/Resources/) native-image)? There are plenty of third party Java libraries which are reading the resource files that are bundled together in the same Jar, how could we overcome this?

PS update:

it is indeed my mistake, confused with `class.getResource()` and `class.getClassLoader().getResource()`. One require slash in the beginning and another doesn't allow. Once I removed the slash in `path` variable, it is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell native image what resources to include via `-H:IncludeResources=path`. The value can be a regular expression.

See the documentation for more details: https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/docs/reference-manual/native-image/Resources.md

Comment: have tried that one, it will only work for the resource in classpath `src/main/resources`, doesn't work if resource is inside jar file.

Comment: @SamYC did you solve the problem? I have the same issue. My project has a dependency jar that contains files inside it and the dependency uses these files. As they are not included, my project doesn't work.

Comment: @JordanSilva yes, my problem is solved, it is mentioned in the "PS" part in my question. I removed the beginning slash in the path variable, then it works.